# segmentation fault 11 in swift2

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have no idea why I get this error.

The problem code is here

```
for i in 0..<itemDataJson?.count {
        imageUrls.append(appDelegate.itemDataJson![i]["image_url"].string!)
}
```

When I `print(itemDataJson?.count)` it prints Optional(1).
What am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's printing Optional(1) because the variable itemDataJson is nullable, so the count would therefore have to be nullable, because we don't know if itemDataJson actually has a value.

The main problem that I see in your code is that you are force-unwrapping variables. Force-unwrapping a variable is a code smell (*usually*, although I do it myself from time to time, but you need to be careful).

When you force unwrap a variable, you need to ask yourself the question, "Do I want the app to crash here if this variable is nil?". If the answer is yes, then using a force unwrap is acceptable, otherwise, you should create a non-nullable variable or if that is not possible, you should use the [guard](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Statements.html) statement in swift.

This could be used like this:

```
guard let itemDataJson = itemDataJson else {
    // itemDataJson was null do something
    return
}
```

You can use the `if let` construct as well, but be careful of the pyramid of doom if you don't use the `if let` construct correctly. See [here](http://nshipster.com/swift-1.2/) for using it correctly, or use a guard statement.

I would recommend checking out the documentation on [optionals](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html) if you have not done so already.

Comment: Thank you! This is perfect explanation!

Answer (score 0):

I would change the code to this version:

```
if (itemDataJson != nil) {
    for i in 0..<itemDataJson!.count {
        imageUrls.append(appDelegate.itemDataJson![i]["image_url"].string!)
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of checking for nil and then use a force unwrap '!', you should use an "if let" : `if let count = itemDataJson?.count {`

Answer (score 0):

You should check all optionals before you try to access the underlying value. Best course of action would be to use `if let` statements.

```
if let itemDataJSON = itemDataJSON {
    for i in 0..<itemDataJSON.count {
        if let items = appDelegate.itemDataJSON {
            if let imageURL = items[i]["imageURL"].string {
                imageUrls.append(imageURL)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Other than that, it's a bad practice to store data in `AppDelegate`. You should create your own data layer that is not dependent of `AppDelegate` to make data handling more efficient and easier.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score -2):

instead of checking for nil you should try this.

```
if let item = itemDataJson {
    for i in 0..<item.count {
         imageUrls.append(appDelegate.itemDataJson![i]["image_url"].string!)
    } 
}
```

Comment: This may still produce segmentation fault because you are unwrapping `itemDataJson` and `string` objects implicitly. Use `if let` for all unwrapping.